# Seeking Documentation and Installation Steps for pymoveit2

Tags: moveit

I am currently working on a project that involves using `pymoveit2` in a ROS 2 environment, and I'm in need of assistance regarding documentation and installation steps.

**Project Overview:**

- I am working on a project in which I want to calculate the inverse kinematics to obtain the joint position of the robot. Since I'm using Python, I've identified `pymoveit2` as a potential solution. However, I encountered an issue during the installation.

**Challenges Faced:**

- When attempting to install `moveitpy2` using the command `pip install pymoveit2`, I encountered the following error:

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymoveit2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pymoveit2

If there are specific steps or dependencies I need to address during installation, your guidance would be highly appreciated.

**Request for Documentation:**

- Kindly point me to any available documentation or tutorials for `pymoveit2`.

**Environment Information:**

- ROS Version: ROS2 Humble
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- Python Version: 3.10.12

I appreciate any guidance, links to documentation, or insights you can provide. Thank you in advance for your support!